# Show content Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, show

I'm trying to show content from a gallery in a #showcontent div. Currently i have this set up

The Js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {
            $(".show-gallery-content").appendTo ("#showcontent").toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

index.php

```
<?php
            $args = array('post_type' => 'Gallery', 'order' => ASC);
            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post($post_id);
                echo '<div class="gallery-item">';


                echo '<div class="gallery-image">';
                the_content();
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="show-gallery-content">';
                echo '<div class="gallery-title">';
                the_title();
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="gallery-excerpt">';
                the_excerpt();
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';


            endwhile;
?>
```

CSS

```
.show-gallery-content {
display:none;
}
```

Live preview of current website -> http://erwin.my89.nl/stage/sieh/

So, when I click an image i want to get the_title() & the_excerpt to show in #showcontent.

I had it fine last night but PhpStorm kinda screwed it up this morning, so i'm really frustrated now :D.

Thanks in advance!

Also i'd like some background information since I'm a student :-)!

Comment: HTML generated doesn't seem to be valid, there is 4 `div` open tags but 5 closing tags.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the notice. Fixed it already :p *edit, there are 5 opening, and 5 closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, consider this snippet:

```
$('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#showcontent').empty().append($(this).find('.show-gallery-content').contents().clone());
});
```

Comment: I knew i would meet my hero today :D! Very nice man! Could you maybe give some info about it? Why does this work and other things not? I'm a student and I really want too learn stuff :)

Comment: Firstly, you should clear content of #showcontent calling the method empty(). Secondly, you search for .show-gallery-content class inside last clicked .gallery-item class. To take html from it, call method contents(). If you would not use method clone(), then content will be taken directly from the .gallery-item, and inside .gallery-item will be no more .show-gallery-content (so when you will click second time on it, there is no any .show-gallery-content inside .gallery-item). So, call method clone(). Thirdly, insert taken html code from .show-gallery-content to the #showcontent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#showcontent").append($(".show-gallery-content").html()).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt work as needed to work. First clicks whos the right content and title but when i click again it shows another title, and it only shows the first title and content

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach for linking photo to content is not optimized solution. anyway, based on your html structure you need a connection between clicked image to content. you can try this snippet.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {
            $(this).children(".show-gallery-content").appendTo ("#showcontent").toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Cool this works. I'll try to get a sort of refresh in the js because its putting all 3 contents now in the div.